# Using Views in a tabbed application

Tags: android

Alright, so I have an application that has a tabbed interface.  What I would like to know is how I can change the currently active View in the tab, and then when I'm done with that View, go back the the original View, exactly as it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to use a ViewFlipper, defined in xml.

```
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ScreenSwitch"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <element A>
    <element B>
    <element C>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Usage is simple, just find the ViewFlipper object throught findViewById() and request changing:

```
viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild( idOfViewToSet );
```

It's then completely up to you, how do you build "tabs".

Comment: The ViewFlipper worked fantastically, thank you for introducing me to this. :)

Comment: You're welcome. I actually use ViewFlipper in my project, even with MapView. But this of course needs some own solutions, I created something like View Managers, so they take care of everything, instead of activities :)

Answer (score 0):

For creating the view, what you probably want is something like this:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MyViewController implements TabHost.TabContentFactory
{
    private View myRootView;

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag)
    {
        if (myRootView == null)
        {
            // TODO: Create your view here by...
            //       1) Constructing it yourself
            //       2) Inflating a layout.xml with LayoutInflater (better)
            myRootView = new View(context);
        }
        return myRootView;
    }
}
```

As for changing tabs programmatically, it is as simple as calling [setCurrentTab()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29) on your TabHost object.